# Wordpress List child category ordby=count

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem. I have this categories and subcategories

```
Main CAT #1
---- Child CAT#1
---- Child CAT#2
---- Child CAT#3

Main CAT #2
---- Child CAT#4
---- Child CAT#5
---- Child CAT#6
```

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve only the child of the Main CAT #2 and Main CAT #1 mashed up and ordered by count.

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=count&order=DESC&title_li' . $category->cat_ID); ?>
```

What is missing? Any idea?

Comment: You would need the category IDs of the main category. Then use the 'child_of' parameter for wp_list_categories to get the child cats for each category. You would loop twice to get all the child cats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a dynamic query you can do, but you could include the following two parameters to flatten the list, and exclude the parent categories:

depth=-1  //all categories displayed in flat (no indent) form

exclude=1,5,7 //exclude certain categories, so you could list your parent categories here by id..